# Minimum distance and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm trying to make a query which give the nearest shop from a city.

I've this table (The result of a query in fac recorded in temporary table)

```
id_Customer | id_Shop | distance
-------------------------------
1           | 1       | 10
1           | 2       | 30
1           | 3       | 100
2           | 3       | 150
2           | 2       | 300
2           | 1       | 400
```

I would have this result (The minimal distance)

```
id_Customer | id_Shop | distance
-------------------------------
1           | 1       | 10
2           | 3       | 150
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please let us know what sql query you have tried till now. This will help us in helping you.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html) is an excellent article in the official MySQL documentation:

Quote:

### The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column

Task: For each article, find the dealer or dealers with the most expensive price.

This problem can be solved with a subquery like this one:

```
SELECT article, dealer, price
FROM   shop s1
WHERE  price=(SELECT MAX(s2.price)
              FROM shop s2
              WHERE s1.article = s2.article);
```

The preceding example uses a correlated subquery, which can be inefficient (see Section 13.2.10.7, “Correlated Subqueries”). Other possibilities for solving the problem are to use an uncorrelated subquery in the FROM clause or a LEFT JOIN.

**Uncorrelated subquery:**

```
SELECT s1.article, dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
JOIN (
  SELECT article, MAX(price) AS price
  FROM shop
  GROUP BY article) AS s2
  ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price = s2.price;
```

**LEFT JOIN:**

```
SELECT s1.article, s1.dealer, s1.price
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.article IS NULL;
```

The LEFT JOIN works on the basis that when s1.price is at its maximum value, there is no s2.price with a greater value and the s2 rows values will be NULL.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.id_Customer, t.id_Shop, t.distance 
from your_table t
inner join 
(
   select id_Customer, min(distance) as m_dis
   from your_table
   group by id_Customer
) x on x.id_Customer = t.id_Customer and t.distance = x.m_dis
```

Comment: Personally I learn way more on an example that fit my problem and not just a general one.

Comment: I couldn't send you my code, but thx for the solution, I understood my mistake.

My subquery contained a Group by on id_Shop and id_Customer :D

So... It solved.

My code is complex because, i simplified a lot for my question but i had nearly the same code that your aswer (except the group by)