# How to get date_of_highest_points

Tags: mysql

I have still problem with select date_of_highest_points:

```
$qry1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO bbdnes_hraci (nick, sumfrags, sumpoints, 
             sumhours, lastdate1,  highest_points, date_of_highest_points)

SELECT DISTINCT nick, SUM(frags), SUM(points), SUM(hours), 
   MAX(lastdate), MAX(points), ?????? 

FROM hraci
GROUP BY nick  ");
```

I asked about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817900/select-in-select ,  but i have not solved it, despite council. Can somebody help me with code?

TABLE: hraci

```
nick  frags   points hours         lastdate              

Gamer1  20      100   1         2013-09-17 22:16:08

Gamer1  30      150   3         2013-09-18 20:17:15

Gamer1  25      125    0.5      2013-09-18 23:16:06

Gamer2  50      250    4        2013-09-17 21:11:30

Gamer2  5        25    2        2013-09-17 23:13:59
```

Need get:

TABLE: bbdnes_hraci

```
nick  sumfrags   sumpoints  sumhours     lastdate1   highest_points   date_of_highest_points

Gamer1  75         375         4.5       2013-09-18 23:16:06   150   2013-09-18 20:17:15 ??

Gamer2  55         275          6        2013-09-17 23:13:59   250  2013-09-17 21:11:30  ??
```

Comment: Find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18737840/447489 And please don't post questions twice. I voted to close your other question as this one is written better. And if you don't use MySQL you can use this answer anyway, cause it uses standard sql, it works on all RDBMS.

Comment: @fancyPants: there is a lot of standard SQL that does not work on MySQL (window functions, common table expressions, DML with sub-selects on the same table - not even the standard string concatenation `||` works on MySQL)

Comment: I tried it and it not work on MySQL. I tried all of that and nothing works. I am noob :( Come code for MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select nick, SUM(frags) sumfrags, SUM(points) sumpoints, SUM([hours]) sumhours, max(lastdate) lastdate, max(points) highest_points
  into #t1
  from hraci
 group by Nick

select t1.*, x.lastdate date_of_highest_points
  from #t1 t1
         outer apply
       (select top 1 lastdate 
          from hraci t
         where t.Nick = t1.Nick and t.points = t1.highest_points
         order by t.lastdate desc) x
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from table_name where highest_points = (select max(highest_points) from table_name)
```

Comment: Wrong. You're missing the "per nick" part.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nick, SUM(frags), SUM(points), SUM(hours), 
       MAX(lastdate), MAX(highest_points),
            (
            SELECT  lastdate As date_of_highest_points
            FROM    hraci
            WHERE   points =(SELECT MAX(points) FROM hraci)
            )
(rest of query. i.e. FROM and ORDER By's)
```

Comment: Thx for reply, but if i use it, so for all Gamers is same  time (time of highest points from table hraci). I need time of highest points for invidual Gamers.